# What does $ means in JavaScript and how can I replace it in a Win8 application?

Tags: javascript, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Example in:

```
   JsDatePick.prototype.setC = function(obj, aClassName){
        if (this.isie && this.iever > 7){
            $(obj).attr("class", aClassName);
        } else {
            obj.className = aClassName;
        }
    };
```

Source: http://javascriptcalendar.org/

Comment: In that particular case, the code that uses `$` is unnecessary (and I'd call it flat-out wrong, but that's just me).  The code in the `else` clause is all that's needed.

Comment: And after looking at that library, I recommend pretty strongly that you avoid it.  It does not evince programming skill on the part of its author.

Answer (score 9):

It is a variable name. It has no special meaning in the language.

A number of libraries (including jQuery and Prototype.js) hang their main function off it.

Before you can replace it (on a general scale), you will have to determine which piece of code is assigning a value to it in the first place.

In this particular case, you can forget about it since all browsers that support setting a class attribute programatically also support setting the `className` property (which the else clause does).

Comment: In this particular case it's a good bet that it's jQuery, and if so that the old code is just bad anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the site?

> Download includes jsDatePick standard full/minified, and jsDatePick
>   for jQuery full/minified.

They already have a non jQuery version.

Comment: This is true, though I don't think I'd want that code anywhere near an application I cared about :-)